# ProxyPass and DocumentRoot on one domain

Tags: apache, document-root, proxypass

Let's say I have the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost domain.com>
    # Server names, admins, logs etc...

    ProxyVia On
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Location "/">
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/tomcat-webapp/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/tomcat-webapp/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I want the address `domain.com/forum` to display content of my MyBB forum, which has its files inside the `/var/www/forum` directory. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Actually, I resolved this problem with the following code:

```
ProxyPass /forum !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/tomcat-webapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/tomcat-webapp/
Alias /forum /var/www/forum
```

Comment: Any idea about this question? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271434/apache-mod-proxy-with-tomcat-and-svn

Comment: @fracz can you post whole .conf file here ?

Comment: Sort of works, but it seems like the permissions are wrong vs using `Directory`?

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Also, for someone noob like me, just replace the whole <Location> .. tag with this -- basically don't add it inside the tag, replace the whole tag with this text . Took a while to realise

Comment: it would nice if you put your whole configuration. I'm new to this thing and not really sure where to put things

Answer (score 3):

What it is recommending is using mod_rewrite to perform the ProxyPass instead of ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse command.

Try something like:

```
RewriteRule  ^/forum   -  [L]
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)    http://localhost:8080/tomcat-webapp/$1  [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /     http://localhost:8080/tomcat-webapp/
```

Comment: This requires `Alias /forum /var/www/forum` to be set before for the rewrite rule to go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#other irrelevant configs here
ProxyPass /forum http://localhost:8080/myBB
ProxyPassReverse /forum http://localhost:8080/myBB
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/tomcat-app
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/tomcat-app
</VirtualHost>
```

You don't have to say "tomcat-app" if your tomcat app is the root app.